# Interceptors and the Business Rules service on Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, business-rules

My ODM application uses interceptors. I am trying to deploy my rules on the Business Rules service on Bluemix. How do I configure the Business Rules service to use interceptors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the use of interceptors is not supported by the Business Rules service on Bluemix. I redesigned my rules so that my application did not depend on interceptors.